# Size of the object in code

Tags: c++

What does the line   **int Test::i;** does in the below program. Somebody Please Explain

```
// Assume that integers take 4 bytes.
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;   

class Test
{
  static int i;
  int j;
};

int Test::i;

int main()
{
    cout << sizeof(Test);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did u want output of program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the syntax for defining a `static` member of a class. It initializes `Test::i` to `0`.

To give it another value, you can do

```
int Tent::i = 42;
```

Comment: Does the standard actually guarantee that it will be initialized to 0?

Comment: @AndreiTita yes, it value-initializes statics defined like that.

Answer (score 2):

```
int Test::i;
```

defines the static member `i` of class `Test` initializing it to `0` by default.

```
static int i;
```

just declares the member `i` but doesn't define it. You need to put the definition separately.

Answer (score 0):

The line in question defines (instantiates) the static variable i in class Test and initializes it to the default value zero.

The program writes out the size of an object of type class Test, which is the size of the int "j" in bytes. The number is platform-dependent. A 32-bit Windows program will write 4.  The variable "i" does not enter into it, because it is not a member of objects of class Test, but rather a "static member", which is like a global except that it is only accessible through the namespace for class Test.